# Percona 5.7 wont autostart after Centos7 machine reboot

Tags: mysql, service, centos, percona

I am running CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core), and I am trying to install Percona SQL server 5.7 from yum repository, using the [official guide](https://docs.percona.com/percona-server/5.7/installation/yum_repo.html).

I used the following steps:

```
$ sudo yum install https://repo.percona.com/yum/percona-release-latest.noarch.rpm
$ sudo percona-release setup ps57
$ yum install Percona-Server-server-57
$ sudo systemctl enable mysql # But in my case it was mysqld, not mysql
```

In regards that last line, if I used what the guide say, I get an error from the OS saying `too many levels of symlinks`. But if I used `mysqld` instead of `mysql`, the symlink in /etc/systemd/system is created:

[image]

At this point, plus a number of other intermediary steps, I have the server up and running. I can log in using an empty root password (`myql -u root -p`) and I can list the databases.

This is all good until I restart the server machine. For some reason, the service won't autostart (but other services like Redis do), and after doing `sudo service mysqld status`, I see this output:

[image]

That would suggest a problem with the server's configuration. However, after doing `sudo service mysqld start`, the service starts just fine. The `mysql.log` file shows something like this:

```
2023-03-18T16:51:17.985324Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2023-03-18T16:51:17.985448Z 0 [Warning] 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' sql mode was not set.
2023-03-18T16:51:17.989952Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.41-44) starting as process 12993 ...
2023-03-18T16:51:17.999577Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2023-03-18T16:51:17.999632Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2023-03-18T16:51:17.999636Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-03-18T16:51:17.999639Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2023-03-18T16:51:17.999642Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2023-03-18T16:51:17.999646Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2023-03-18T16:51:18.002025Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-03-18T16:51:18.002187Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2023-03-18T16:51:18.004762Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2023-03-18T16:51:18.124386Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-03-18T16:51:18.142600Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2023-03-18T16:51:18.221724Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Crash recovery did not find the parallel doublewrite buffer at /var/lib/mysql/xb_doublewrite
2023-03-18T16:51:18.224274Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2023-03-18T16:51:18.268156Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Created parallel doublewrite buffer at /var/lib/mysql/xb_doublewrite, size 3932160 bytes
2023-03-18T16:51:18.382883Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-03-18T16:51:18.383006Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-03-18T16:51:18.595726Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-03-18T16:51:18.633395Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2023-03-18T16:51:18.633436Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2023-03-18T16:51:18.665733Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2023-03-18T16:51:18.734039Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.7.41-44 started; log sequence number 2768817
2023-03-18T16:51:18.772089Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2023-03-18T16:51:18.772374Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2023-03-18T16:51:18.925210Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
2023-03-18T16:51:18.925248Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
2023-03-18T16:51:18.925253Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
2023-03-18T16:51:18.925255Z 0 [Warning] A deprecated TLS version TLSv1.1 is enabled. Please use TLSv1.2 or higher.
2023-03-18T16:51:18.925708Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 230318 16:51:18
2023-03-18T16:51:18.926907Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2023-03-18T16:51:18.926992Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
2023-03-18T16:51:18.927494Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2023-03-18T16:51:18.964455Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is not available.
2023-03-18T16:51:18.964503Z 0 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
2023-03-18T16:51:18.964531Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2023-03-18T16:51:18.990121Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2023-03-18T16:51:19.027108Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.41-44'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Percona Server (GPL), Release 44, Revision 27f408641db
```

I don't see a connection between those warnings and the inability of the service to auto-start. Shutting down the machine with the Mysql server running and restarting it again would render the problem again, with the service down.

Also, I have no idea which is that missing dependency that the service logs are talking about.

This is the `my.cnf` configuration file:

[image]

Comment: What are you using to SHUTDOWN the running instance?

Comment: `sudo shutdown -r now`

Comment: I would try from LX Command Prompt, service mysqld stop  - for a more orderly stop on the one service named mysqld.    Let us know if this enables less troublesome start.  
Credit for the tip goes to url - https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-administration/stop-mysql/

Comment: Thanks @Wilson Hauck, but that is not the problem I am trying to resolve. The problem is to start the service automatically after the machine reboots. The mysqld service won't start automatically even though it is enabled

Comment: Try my suggestion, verify the SERVICE is not running with HTOP or TOP,  then try your sudo to stop and restart the world - which is HIGH HAZARD.  MySQL needs 'service mysqld stop' for an ORDERLY SHUTDOWN which includes in flight buffer management and lots of other details..  You also NEED Global Variable innodb_fast_shutdown=0 (for OFF) in your my.cnf for your instance to have a more orderly shutdown than just dropping it like a ROCK.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, I added that configuration to `my.cnf`, but didn't fix the problem (I restarted the machine several times). I checked that the service is not running with `ps aux | grep -i 'mysql'`, and that returned nothing. The command `systemctl mysqld status` returned the same output as I already described in the description. I'll add the `my.cnf` file to that description.

Comment: We are way past one question/one answer.  Please view profile for contact info and get in touch via Skype.  Normailly here daylight hours GMT -5 hours.

Comment: Sorry @WilsonHauck, I am not interested in consultancy services. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, in your my.cnf consider these changes,

Use only underscores, not hyphens when naming the Global Variable to be set.

Change symbolic-links to have_symlinks
There is NO GLOBAL VARIABLE named symbolic-links

Remove sql_mode line.  ="" is not a valid listed option.

This URL https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html -
indicates in datadir descriptive text when autostarting it should be your
full path  value i.e. lead with something like M: or C: and the rest of the path.

Many people have an additional folder at the end of your string for /data
to avoid any question about WHERE the data folder lives.

Minor performance is gained because the LS length will be less entries when
data is in a folder with a single purpose.

Good luck.  Later.

Comment: @Nicolas PS Your zuzsso.com is not really available.